# AjaxControlToolkit Charting Requirements

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to start using the charting objects in the Ajax Control Toolkit but I don't seem to have access to the controls (the chart options are not available in my toolkit).  Are there frame work requirements to use this?  My web application is built on .Net 4.0, I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and the toolkit version is 4.1.60919.  What am I missing?  I don't have an option to change my IDE or framework.  If it is a limitation due to these two things, does anyone have any options for a free, light weight, charting options?

Thanks

Comment: There's a Charting framework alternative that you can use:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx  Are you saying you don't see the controls in your toolbox in VS, or something else?

Comment: Yeah, the controls dont show up in the toolbox with the other ajax controls nor do they show up in intelisense.